# Show related data inside another modal's class-based view

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project that manages different servers and the whitelist associated with each server. I would like to show the associated whitelist for the server in the server's DetailView page. Right now, I have this sort of working by simply calling the Django HTML escapes for the whitelist objects in my template. This works okay but I would like to enable the end user to create/update/delete these whitelists from the respective server detail pages. Here are the two models:

```
#from models.py

class Server(models.Model):
     server_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
     customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     sw_vendor = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SW_VENDORS_CHOICES)
     sw_version = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
     pb_method = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = PB_METHOD_CHOICES)
     date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     history = HistoricalRecords()

     def __str__(self):
          return self.server_url

     def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse('proxyadmin-server-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

#and

class Whitelist(models.Model):
     reference = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
     customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     server = models.OneToOneField(Server, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     applications = models.ManyToManyField('Application')
     date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     def __str__(self):
          return self.reference
```

I tried creating CBVs for Whitelist and referencing it in the template but ran into a Reverse URL error filtering because I could not figure out how to filter the whitelist by any of the Server field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need to see additional code, I am not sure exactly what needs to be seen to answer my question.

**EDIT**

Below is some additional code for what I have.

```
#from views.py

class ServerDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
     model = Server

class WhitelistDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
     model = Whitelist
```

and:

```
#from urls.py

from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    ServerListView,
    ServerDetailView,
    ServerCreateView,
    ServerUpdateView,
    ServerDeleteView,
    WhitelistDetailView
)
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='proxyadmin-home'),
    path('customers/', views.customers, name='proxyadmin-customers'),
    path('servers/', ServerListView.as_view(extra_context={'title': 'Servers', 'servers_page': "active"}), name='proxyadmin-servers'),
    path('servers/<int:pk>/', ServerDetailView.as_view(extra_context={'title': 'Servers', 'servers_page': "active"}), name='proxyadmin-server-detail'),
    path('servers/new/', ServerCreateView.as_view(extra_context={'title': "Servers", 'servers_page': "active", 'heading': "Create Server"}), name='proxyadmin-server-create'),
    path('servers/<int:pk>/edit/', ServerUpdateView.as_view(extra_context={'title': "Servers", 'servers_page': "active", 'heading': "Edit Server"}), name='proxyadmin-server-edit'),
    path('servers/<int:pk>/delete/', ServerDeleteView.as_view(extra_context={'title': "Servers", 'servers_page': "active", 'heading': "Delete Server"}), name='proxyadmin-server-delete'),
    path('whitelists/<int:pk>/', WhitelistDetailView.as_view(extra_context={'title': 'Whitelists'}), name='proxyadmin-whitelist-detail'),
]
```

In my Server template, I am trying to just have a link to the associated whitelist as proof of concept. In the future I will want to display a table of the info from the Whitelist model with the info.

```
<a href="{% url 'proxyadmin-whitelist-detail' %}">View Whitelist</a>
```

The error I get back when I click this link is:

```
NoReverseMatch at /servers/1/
Reverse for 'proxyadmin-whitelist-detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['whitelists/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/servers/1/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
```

Comment: Add what errors you have got and views, templates (and urls.py)

Comment: I edited my post with the info you asked for.

Comment: Yes it does, I added a server.id parameter to the link and I am getting data back. Thank you and sorry for the stupid question!

Answer (score 0):

you can override the get context data method and add additional contexts

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MainView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['other_datas'] = OtherModel.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: I added this code but not sure what to do with the context. I have passed context directly into my urls.py for titles and link highlighting purposes. I have edited my post with views and urls.

Answer (score 0):

I added a parameter to the link in my template (based on comment on my question) and was able to see the data:

```
<a href="{% url 'proxyadmin-whitelist-detail' server.id %}">View Whitelist</a>
```